# Cannot set libreoffice UI to another language from DEBS

Tags: libreoffice, language-support

After first installing the base libreoffice packages, and then installing the local language packages as intended in the [documentation](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/Documentation/Install/Linux#Setting_Up_a_Language_Pack),
I am sadly unable to select the desired language in the user interface language option.

Does anyone know how to install a language user interface from the debs provided by the libreoffice website ?

I was able to install the desired translated user interface by installing the libreoffice-l10n-fr package but the question remains, Why did the recommended installation (by downloading the debs from the official website and installing them) did not work in the first place ?

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS, the problem occurs on Libreoffice
installed via LibreOffice_7.5.0_Linux_x86-64_deb package downloaded on libreoffice website alongside the LibreOffice_7.5.0_Linux_x86-64_deb_langpack_fr package

Comment: @guiverc I just edited my question to provide these informations.

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu there is no need to go to LibreOffice upstream for installing translations. The simplest way to install a language is described here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/prefs-language-install.html

When installing a language there, the translations for that language — including the applicable `libreoffice-l10n-*` package — gets installed.